# Reading in tab delimited numbers into large array

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to read in a list of numbers separated by tabs into a large array. I need every number to be it's own element but no matter what i try it seems to group them by row. The text file I am reading from looks like this:

```
 348548 141913 489224  81717 403131

 143034 876953 784947 593480 355401
```

with many more row of numbers. I finally have functional code that is reading data from the file:

```
array = []
 with open('rand1000.txt', 'r') as file:
 numbers = file.readlines()
 for line in numbers:
    position = line[:-1]
    array.append(position)
```

but when I print the array I get this:

> [' 348548 141913 489224  81717 403131', '', ' 143034 876953 784947
>   593480 355401', '', ' 200777 855598 470624 438334 967124', '', '
>   314937 673395  78981 748181 738558', '', ' 160619 305980 330514 143635
>   269516', '', ' 443338 897870 533897 549242 542277', '', ' 730654
>   619923  80681   4641 945810', '', ' 403894 791515 299325 794329 
>   44805', '', ' 274761 525591 385985 945151 992758', '', ' 318335
>   539269]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read each line and then strip the `new line character` from each line. Afterwards, you have to `split` the line on basis of `tab (\t)`. Finally you can add it t array.

Note my `if`condition. it accounts for case where there is nothing on the line. 
There you go:

```
array = []
with open('file.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        line = line.strip('\n').split('\t')
        if not (len(line) == 0 or line[0] is ''):
            for number in line:
                array.append(int(number))
```

Comment: The questions asks for "every number to be it's own element" so your code does that properly where mine only separated the numbers but then left them in a 2d list. The questioner will need to decide if preventing blank rows from entering array is desirable or not (though it likely will be desired).

Answer (score 0):

if you want elements as single integers try this

```
    position = line[:-1].split()
    for num in position:
        array.append(int(num))
```

this will return followimg array

```
[348548, 141913, 489224, 81717, 40313, 143034, 876953, 784947, 593480, 35540]
```

for single string elements

```
position = line[:-1].split()
for num in position:
    array.append(num)
```

And the output

```
['348548', '141913', '489224', '81717', '403131', '143034', '876953', '784947', '593480', '355401']
```

if you want rows separate use this

```
        position = line[:-1].split()
        row = []
        for num in position:
            row.append(num)
        if len(row) > 0:
            array.append(row)
```

output look like this

```
[['348548', '141913', '489224', '81717', '403131'], ['143034', '876953', '784947', '593480', '355401']]
```